# Java Max-Stack implementation to return maximum value in the stack

Tags: java, stack

I have written the below program to write a Java stack implementation. I have added a method which returns the maximum value in the stack, e.g, a pop. The implementation for this is based on the Max Heap Sort algorithim. I have little doubt on the time complexity analysis - it's not \$O(\log n)\$ is it?

```
public class Stack {

    int top = -1;
    int[] stack;

    public Stack(int size) {
        stack = new int[size];
    }

    public void push(int v) {
        if (top == stack.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("Oveflow!!");
            return;
        }
        stack[++top] = v;
    }

    public void pop() {
        if (top < 0) {
            System.out.println("Empty stack");
            return;
        }

        stack[top] = 0;
        top--;

    }

    public int getMax() {

        int[] c = stack.clone();
         // not a complete heap sort, but with below approach, i am trying bubble up.
        // build the heap starting from n/2, as any nodes after n/2 are leaf(s)
        for (int j = stack.length / 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            buildMaxHeap(c, j, c.length - 1);
        }

        return c[0];
    }

    private void buildMaxHeap(int[] clone, int i, int j) {
        int root = i;

        while (root * 2 + 1 <= j) {
            int c = root * 2 + 1;

            if ((c + 1) <= j && clone[c] <= clone[c + 1]) {
                c = c + 1;

            }

            if (clone[root] < clone[c]) {
                int t = clone[root];
                clone[root] = clone[c];
                clone[c] = t;
                root = c;
            } else {
                root++;
            }
        }

    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(stack[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Running time:**

The running time is not O(lg(n)) is O(n) since you are building a max heap.

You iterate over [image] elements (no leaf elements). Knowing this we can conclude that is at least O(n).
The function called buildMaxHeap is actually O(h), h being the height of the node (which you call i). So because the height of any heap is [image]

[image]

and because this summation to the infinity ends up being constant:

[image]

we get O(n).

**Names:**

buildMaxHeap doesn't actually builds the max heap so it name is not appropriate. This function is commonly called maxheapify and is to maintain the heap property. Also I would change the name of parameter named clone for something more generic, because in that context it doesn't matter if its a clone or not.

**Pop:**

Pop doesn't return the element poped, neither I see a top function so this stack is pointless.

**Code**

This part:

```
 if ((c + 1) <= j && clone[c] <= clone[c + 1]) {
     c = c + 1;
 }
```

Can be change to this

```
 if ((c + 1) <= j && clone[c] < clone[c + 1]) {
     ++c;
 }
```

Because if both are equal why bother incrementing c ?

This is not that important though I am just nitpicking.

This part could be improved as well:

```
 if (clone[root] < clone[c]) {
    int t = clone[root];
    clone[root] = clone[c];
    clone[c] = t;
    root = c;
 } else {
    root++;
 }
```

For the swapping it would be more readable to implement a method named swap. Also if there is no swapping the algorithm should terminate, because the lower subtrees are already max heaps so its pointless. This is the reason why building a max heap starts at floor(n/2).

so this part would end up like this

```
 if (clone[root] >= clone[c]) break; 

 swap(clone, root, c);
 root = c;
```

**Conclusion:**

Given the hidden constant factor in your function getMax (cloning the array and the hidden constant factor in building a max heap) its better to do it the straightforward way:

```
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i <= top; ++i)
        max = Math.max(max, stack[i]);
```

or for Java 8:

```
    OptionalInt i = Arrays.stream(stack,0, top+1).max();
```

**Additional notes:**
This also can be improved with Java generics.

Answer (score 2):

## Pop doesn't return value

I'm not sure what your stack is used for.  Your `pop()` function doesn't return the value of the top of the stack.  So, is the only thing the stack is used for to return the maximum value?

## Getting max value in constant time

You can get the maximum value in \$O(1)\$ time if you keep a second stack dedicated to holding the maximum value at each stack level.  In fact, if your `pop()` function isn't going to return a value, you can get rid of your original stack and only keep `maxstack`.  Here is a rewrite of your implementation, which also changes `pop()` to return a value.

```
public class Stack {

    int top = -1;
    int[] stack;
    int[] maxstack;

    public Stack(int size) {
        stack = new int[size];
        maxstack = new int[size];
    }

    public void push(int v) {
        if (top == stack.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("Overflow!!");
            return;
        }
        stack[++top] = v;
        if (top == 0 || v >= maxstack[top-1]) {
            maxstack[top] = v;
        } else {
            maxstack[top] = maxstack[top-1];
        }
    }

    public int pop() {
        if (top < 0) {
            System.out.println("Empty stack");
            return 0;
        }
        return stack[top--];
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return maxstack[top];
    }
}
```